# java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat

Tags: ioexception

**java.io.IOException: The byte array is not a recognized imageformat.**
How can solve this problem.?

Note: I got this error in the company project.Therefore i can't publish my codes...

Comment: You need to provide some clue to how the byte array is made up. Also, the java image API's don't knnow all image formats. Extensions can be found on the web.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I need to send the string parameter. Codes do not see methods when I use byte array. And i have jasperreport. So, i must see this image in jasperreport.